# nodejs getting another page

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I have a small problem about nodejs and html. There is an error somewhere that I couldn't see. I have been getting this error for 2 days. (cannot get /aP.html)
There is nothing wrong about sql connection, and first and second pages. But when I want to go aP.html from secondpage I keep getting this error.
My nodejs code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');



var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    ......
});
connection.connect((err) => {
    if(err){ 
    throw err;}
   else console.log("connected");
});

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true})); //forma girilen datanın parse edilebilmesi için 

//başka directorylerdeki klasörleri kullanacaksan   
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '.....'));

//gidilecek sayfa
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    res.render('/aP.html', {});;
});
    console.log("got it");

app.post('/aP.html', function(request, response) {
    var p_name   = request.body.urun_adi;
    var code = request.body.barkod;
    var quantity   = request.body.stok_sayi;
    var price = request.body.satis_fiyati;
    var cost   = request.body.maliyet;
    var supplier = request.body.firma_adi;
  //  var username = request.body.id;
/* foreign key olan user id burada kullanılacak mı?*/
    console.log(p_name);

       connection.query( "INSERT INTO `stok` (`urun_adi`, `barkod`, `stok_sayi`, `satis_fiyati`, `maliyet`, `firma_adi`) VALUES ('"+p_name +"','"+ code +"','"+ quantity +"','"+ price +"','"+ cost +"','"+ supplier+"')");

                        if(err) throw err;
                        response.send('save succesful');

                });


app.listen(3000);
```

My HTML code(just for trying):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="/aP.html" method="post" class= "col s12">
    <input type="hidden" name="e_id" value="">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="p_name" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Adı</label>
        <div class="col10">
            <input type="text" name="p_name" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="code" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Barkod</label>
        <div class="col10">
            <input type="text" name="code" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="quantity" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Adet</label>
        <div class="col10">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="price" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Fiyat</label>
        <div class="col10">
            <input type="text" name="price" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="cost" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Maliyet</label>
        <div class="col10">
            <input type="text" name="cost" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="supplier" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Tedarikçi</label>
        <div class="col10">
            <input type="text" name="supplier" value="" class="form-control">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Stock">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What view engine are you using? If it is ejs you will have to require it and change some of your code. Look at my example and maybe it will clear things up for you. If this is your question.

first npm install ejs

Index.js or server.js depending on what you name it. (start file)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.set("port", 3001)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index')
});

app.use('*', function (req, res) {
    res.status(400);
    res.json({
        'error': 'Deze URL is niet beschikbaar.'
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, function() {
    console.log('De server luistert op port ' + app.get('port'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Then create a **views** directory in the root of the project. (same level as the index.js) It is important that you name it that.

In the views folder create a file (in your case aP) with .ejs extension. No HTML extension, because you will use the ejs view engine. It will automatically search in de views directory for the ejs files. Put the html code from aP.html into the newly created aP.ejs file.

I hope this is the answer you are looking for if there are any other problems or you want to do it differently, please let me know.

**Edit: different way without ejs**

Change this line:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    res.render('/aP.html', {});;
});
```

Into this:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/aP.html'));;
});
```

Make sure the aP.html is on the same level as the index.js file.

Your problem was (I think) that is didn't recognize res because you name it response. Furthermore you should use sendFile and it will work. I hope this helped.

Comment: actually I was trying to do this with just nodejs-express, html, and mysql. But I guess this won't be applicable(not easily at least).

Comment: Please look at my edit. I thinks this fixes your problem.

Comment: Please look at the answer. If you set it as answer (if it helped of course) it can help more people.

Comment: I am really sorry, I wasn't here for a few days. response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/aP.html')); -- this line worked for me thanks.